# How to focus on the playing track in Clementine audio player?

Tags: audio, playlists

[Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/) allows the use of multiple playlists as tabs - and it would be helpful to always be able to **jump to playing playlist and see/focus on the playing track** by a simple act like clicking somewhere or using a short-key (e.g. foobar2000 does this by double clicking the status bar). Is this possible?

I see under 'Playlist' menu the entry 'Jump to the currently plying track' (Ctrl-J) - but this works in the same playlist (tab), not if a different playlist is selected.

I do not think this is OS specific - but I mostly use it in Ubuntu with Xfce. (Clementine latest, 1.1.)

Comment: Which OS? Clementine has versions for Windows, OSX, Linux etc

Comment: @terdon - added that info

Comment: Thank's, I doubt it is OS specific too but you never know, there are sometimes subtle differences between implementations. Also remember to include which version of the program you are running, your problem _might_ be version dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clementine can focus on the playing track but **only within the selected playlist** by pressing CTRL-J  keys or going to 'Playlist'-'Jump to...'

Luckily, the non-selected playlist that contains  the playing track is signaled by an arrow - so it is visible to be selected. **After** that, using CTRL-J will focus on the playing track.

[image]